# Aec assemblies in forge design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

In the Autocad engine within design automation, can we also make use of the Aec assemblies?

```
using AecDb = Autodesk.Aec.DatabaseServices;
using AecPropDb = Autodesk.Aec.PropertyData.DatabaseServices;
```

This is in order to access the property set data.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD engine comes with AEC Object Enablers (a collection of AEC DBX modules). But, I don't think the AutoCAD Architecture .NET API layer is part of the engine. As such, I don't think your .NET app based on the AEC .NET API will work.

Comment: Hi Qun, thanks for that. I've been doing some more testing, it's true that the .NET API is not part of the engine, but if you bundle the needed DLLs (AecArchMgd, AecBaseMgd, AecPropDataMgd) with the script, it will actually work.

Comment: Hi jorisjh, Glad to hear that you can bundle up the AEC .NET API modules as an appbundle to make your app work. We are also looking at the possibility to include the AEC .NET API layer into our engine.